# Unable to start Node on system reboot Ubuntu Crontab

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, cron, forever

I have tried this with adding the forever start code in `/etc/rc.local` didn't work.

When I use the `@reboot` keyword in `/etc/rc.local` it says `@reboot` cannot be found.

So I went back to using `crontab` Here is my crontab script. All other crontabs are working except the reboot one. In `syslog`, it says

```
Jun  4 09:51:12 ip-172-31-28-35 /usr/sbin/irqbalance: Balancing is ineffective on systems with a single cache domain.  Shutting down
Jun  4 09:51:12 ip-172-31-28-35 cron[959]: (CRON) STARTUP (fork ok)
Jun  4 09:51:12 ip-172-31-28-35 cron[959]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Jun  4 09:51:12 ip-172-31-28-35 CRON[1005]: (ubuntu) CMD (/usr/bin/sudo -u ubuntu /usr/local/bin/forever start home/ubuntu/chat2/index.js)
```

Which shows that the reboot command in my cron tab is working but for some reason forever is still not starting node. After reboot , I run forever list and it says `No forever processes running`

I am assuming the problem is somehow with the **node and forever paths.** I am new to this and dont know which exact path to use on this statement in crontab.

[image]

I have also tried the following:

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/forever start -c /usr/local/bin/node /home/ubuntu/chat2/index.js
```

and

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/forever start /home/ubuntu/chat2/index.js
```

None of these are working.

If I run `which forever` it says

```
/usr/local/bin/forever
```

If I run `which node` it says

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

If I get the full path of my index.js app file, by doing `readlink -f index.js` in my chat2 directory it says

```
/home/ubuntu/chat2/index.js
```

I just want to run this command every time my system reboots. I want to start my node app. The following line works perfect when I cd to the chat2 directory manually. I want this to work on reboot itself.

```
forever -m5000 -w start index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service with you code instead of using cron. Actually I prefer that because you can stop or start it whenever you want and you can also run it on the system reboot or start.

So:

1- Create a service in /etc/init.d/name_of_file

```
#!/bin/bash
#/etc/init.d/name_of_file
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          name
# Required-Start:    $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: add service
# Description:
#
### END INIT INFO

# Some things that run always

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting app_name "
    touch /var/lock/app_name
    cd /where/is/your/file
    node index.js &
    ;;
  stop)
    echo " Stopping "
    rm /var/lock/app_name
    sudo pkill -f node
    ;;
  status)
   if [ -e /var/lock/app_name ]
   then
        echo "app_name is running"
   else
        echo "app_name is not running"
   fi
   ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage:service app_name{start|stop|status}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

So after that you have created a service for running you nodejs application.

You have to give running permission to that script

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/app_name
```

Now the only thing you have to do is configure this to run on boot.

Run:

```
sudo update-rc.d app_name defaults
```

And then every time you reboot you computer the service will start itself.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest redirect stdout/stderr to file to debug why your script in crontab not work:

/usr/local/bin/forever start -c /usr/local/bin/node /home/ubuntu/chat2/index.js >/tmp/forever.log 2>&1 &

See log file for details after reboot.

You also can try [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) , like forever but support buildin system start script generate, and will launch your apps after reboot.